# How to set the authorization header using cURL

Tags: curl, http-authentication

How do I pass authorization header using cURL? ( executable in `/usr/bin/curl`).

Answer (score 513, accepted):

http://curl.se/docs/httpscripting.html

See part 6. HTTP Authentication

> HTTP Authentication

> HTTP Authentication is the ability to tell the server your username and
> password so that it can verify that you're allowed to do the request you're
> doing. The Basic authentication used in HTTP (which is the type curl uses by
> default) is *plain* *text* based, which means it sends username and password
> only slightly obfuscated, but still fully readable by anyone that sniffs on
> the network between you and the remote server.

> To tell curl to use a user and password for authentication:

> ```
> curl --user name:password http://www.example.com
> ```

> The site might require a different authentication method (check the headers
> returned by the server), and then --ntlm, --digest, --negotiate or even
> --anyauth might be options that suit you.

> Sometimes your HTTP access is only available through the use of a HTTP
> proxy. This seems to be especially common at various companies. A HTTP proxy
> may require its own user and password to allow the client to get through to
> the Internet. To specify those with curl, run something like:

> ```
> curl --proxy-user proxyuser:proxypassword curl.haxx.se
> ```

> If your proxy requires the authentication to be done using the NTLM method,
> use --proxy-ntlm, if it requires Digest use --proxy-digest.

> If you use any one these user+password options but leave out the password
> part, curl will prompt for the password interactively.

> Do note that when a program is run, its parameters might be possible to see
> when listing the running processes of the system. Thus, other users may be
> able to watch your passwords if you pass them as plain command line
> options. There are ways to circumvent this.

> It is worth noting that while this is how HTTP Authentication works, very
> many web sites will not use this concept when they provide logins etc. See
> the Web Login chapter further below for more details on that.

Comment: @Vixed This question is explicitly not about PHP. [What's wrong with Google's results](s)?

Comment: The question is about Authorization not authentication, so maybe the OP should change the title of the question

Answer (score 489):

Just adding so you don't have to click-through:

```
curl --user name:password http://www.example.com
```

or if you're trying to do send authentication for OAuth 2:

```
curl -H "Authorization: OAuth <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://www.example.com
```

Comment: Many API now use header authorization tokens. The `-H` option is great.

Comment: If you use -u or --user, Curl will Encode the credentials into Base64 and produce a header like this: `-H Authorization: Basic <Base64EncodedCredentials>`

Comment: I'm trying to add an authorization header with `HMAC-SHA256` always getting an error of missing authorization header

Comment: Additionally, if you need the `<Base64EncodedCredentials>` as mentioned by @timothy-kansaki, you can get the encoded credential using the command: `cred="$( echo $NAME:$PASSWORD | base64 )"; curl -H "Authorization: Basic $cred" https://example.com`. For reference, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16918602/how-to-base64-encode-image-in-linux-bash-shell

Comment: @DavidGolembiowski   by default echo will throw in a newline, at least on macs.  As mentioned in your link, you'll want `echo -n` to prevent the newline from being included

Comment: ... or better use `creds="$(printf $NAME:$PASSWORD | base64)"`

Answer (score 262):

Bearer tokens look like this:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <ACCESS_TOKEN>" http://www.example.com
```

Comment: And if you're looking to do 'Basic' authorisation, just swap 'Bearer' for 'Basic'

Comment: I've got the strangest thing, I'm getting a "Wrong format of Authorization header" and "HTTP-200". So the server accepts my authorization, but the format is wrong?

Answer (score 115):

This worked for me:

```sh
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://www.example.com/
```

Comment: what are you using for JWT ?

Comment: Don't you mean `Authorization: bearer xxxxxxxxx`?

Comment: @jlh you mean `Bearer`

Comment: I was almost sure that it's case-insensitive, but it seems I'm wrong. Yes I meant `Bearer`.

Answer (score 76):

(for those who are looking for [php-curl](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) answer)

```
$service_url = 'https://example.com/something/something.json';
$curl = curl_init($service_url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "username:password"); //Your credentials goes here
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //IMP if the url has https and you don't want to verify source certificate

$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
$response = json_decode($curl_response);
curl_close($curl);

var_dump($response);
```

Answer (score 30):

For HTTP Basic Auth:

`curl -H "Authorization: Basic <_your_token_>" http://www.example.com`

replace `_your_token_` and the URL.

Comment: When using oauth where would the Authorization token come from?  I am trying to use curl to download files from a site where I use a user and password but it seems to be failing due to oauth2 in use.

Comment: @toasteez you have to go through the Oauth2 flow to receive a token. Typically its a two step process and should be detailed in the server's documentation.

Comment: good answer. a small helper `echo -ne "<your-user>:<your-pass>" | base64 --wrap 0` will generate the basic auth token.

Comment: @MikeD `-H "Authorization: Basic <_your_token_>"` does the same effect as `--user login:password`. You can check it with `curl -v`

Comment: @vladkras my response is a _helper_ for this answer. in my experience, it is better to understand how to create the token instead of relying on curl to generate it.

Answer (score 19):

Be careful that when you using:
`curl -H "Authorization: token_str" http://www.example.com`

`token_str` and `Authorization` must be separated by white space, otherwise server-side will not get the `HTTP_AUTHORIZATION` environment.

Comment: Not true, if a white space is required, your HTTP server is broken. Also you need two strings a type and then the token.

Answer (score 11):

This example includes the following:

- POST request
- Header Content-Type
- Header Authorization
- Data flag with JSON data
- Base64 encoded token
- Ref-1: [curl authorization header](https://www.shellhacks.com/curl-add-header-multiple-headers-authorization/)
- Ref-2: [curl POST request](https://linuxize.com/post/curl-post-request/)

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"name”:”Johnny B. Goode”, "email”:”johnny.b.goode@mail.com"}' -H "Authorization: Bearer $(echo -n  Guitar Maestro | base64)" https://url-address.com
```

Answer (score 10):

If you don't have the token at the time of the call is made, You will have to make two calls, one to get the token and the other to extract the token form the response, pay attention to

> grep token | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d\" -f4

as it is the part which is dealing with extracting the token from the response.

```
echo "Getting token response and extracting token"    
def token = sh (returnStdout: true, script: """
    curl -S -i -k -X POST https://www.example.com/getToken -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -H \"Accept: application/json\" -d @requestFile.json | grep token | cut -d, -f1 | cut -d\\" -f4
""").split()
```

After extracting the token you can use the token to make subsequent calls as follows.

```
echo "Token : ${token[-1]}"       
echo "Making calls using token..."       
curl -S -i -k  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${token[-1]}" https://www.example.com/api/resources
```

Answer (score 10):

As of `curl` 7.61.0 you can use the `--oauth2-bearer <token>` option to set the correct Bearer authorization headers.

Answer (score 9):

FWIW, on Mac OS I've found that I need to surround the target url with quotes when it contains query parameters, e.g.,

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" "https://www.example.com/?param=myparam"
```

Comment: what tool  i can use to get base64 string, can I just use any online tool ? like `https://www.base64encode.org/`?

Answer (score 4):

The below worked for me

```
curl -H "Authorization: Token xxxxxxxxxxxxxx" https://www.example.com/
```

Answer (score 3):

For those doing Token-Based authentication ... make sure you do :

curl -H "AuthToken: "

instead !!

Answer (score 1):

A simple example is using parameters with authorization converted to base64

```
curl -XPOST 'http://exemplo.com/webhooks?Authorization=Basic%20dGVzdDoxMjM0NTYK'
```