# How to base64 encode image in linux bash / shell

Tags: linux, image, shell, variables, base64

I'm trying to base64 encode an image in a shell script and put it into variable:

```
test="$(printf DSC_0251.JPG | base64)"
echo $test
RFNDXzAyNTEuSlBH
```

I've also tried something like this:

```
test=\`echo -ne DSC_0251.JPG | base64\`
```

but still with no success.

I want to do something like this:

```
curl -v -X POST -d '{"image":$IMAGE_BASE64,"location":$LOCATION,"time_created":$TIMECREATED}' -H 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF8' http://192.168.1.1/upload
```

I found this http://www.zzzxo.com/q/answers-bash-base64-encode-script-not-encoding-right-12290484.html

but still have had no success.

Answer (score 220, accepted):

You need to use `cat` to get the *contents* of the file named 'DSC_0251.JPG', rather than the filename itself.

```
test="$(cat DSC_0251.JPG | base64)"
```

However, `base64` can read from the file itself:

```
test=$( base64 DSC_0251.JPG )
```

Comment: with cat it works, great thanks a lot man. I know that it can read from file, but it still has problems to store it in variable so test="$(cat DSC_0251.JPG | base64)" works for me.

Comment: What problems? The two commands above should produce identical results, except the first is a [useless use of cat](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html).

Comment: you are right. This is what should I do `$RESPONSE="$(curl -v -X POST -d '{"image":\`base64|$DIR$IMAGE\`,"location":$LOCATION,"time_created":$TIMECREATED}' -H 'Content-type: text/plain; charset=UTF8' --max-time 180 -s $URL)";`

Comment: I'm not a big Linux specialist, but isn't it a ` symbol that you should enclose command into to put results in variable?

Comment: `cat vlc.jpg | base64 -w 0  ` - in case someone want output as string to copy and paste.

Comment: @DavidJashi `$()` is very similar and easier to nest.

Comment: What's wrong with `base64 DSC_0251.JPG`? There is no need to run through the `cat` filter when the program takes a file as arguments (`base64 [OPTIONS] [FILE]`)

Comment: @Eric Nothing; the first example just demonstrates what the OP was doing wrong by using `printf`; the second example does exactly what you suggest.

Comment: `< DSC_0251.JPG base64` would probably be a bit better than `cat` while maintaining the same left-to-right reading order.

Comment: I only mentioned `cat` as a command that, unlike `printf`, reads the contents of a file before segueing to having `base64` read the file itself. I'm not away of any significant difference between `base64 DSC_0251.jpg` and `base64 < DSC_0251.jpg`.

Answer (score 117):

## Encode

### On Linux

Single line result:

```bash
base64 -w 0 DSC_0251.JPG
```

For `HTML`:

```bash
echo "data:image/jpeg;base64,$(base64 -w 0 DSC_0251.JPG)"
```

As file:

```bash
base64 -w 0 DSC_0251.JPG > DSC_0251.JPG.base64
```

In variable:

```bash
IMAGE_BASE64="$(base64 -w 0 DSC_0251.JPG)"
```

In variable for `HTML`:

```bash
IMAGE_BASE64="data:image/jpeg;base64,$(base64 -w 0 DSC_0251.JPG)"
```

### On OSX

On *OSX*, the `base64` binary is different, and the parameters are different. If you want to use it on *OSX*, you should remove `-w 0`.

Single line result:

```bash
base64 DSC_0251.JPG
```

For `HTML`:

```bash
echo "data:image/jpeg;base64,$(base64 DSC_0251.JPG)"
```

As file:

```bash
base64 DSC_0251.JPG > DSC_0251.JPG.base64
```

In variable:

```bash
IMAGE_BASE64="$(base64 DSC_0251.JPG)"
```

In variable for `HTML`:

```bash
IMAGE_BASE64="data:image/jpeg;base64,$(base64 DSC_0251.JPG)"
```

### Generic OSX/Linux

#### As Shell Function

```bash
@base64() {
  if [[ "${OSTYPE}" = darwin* ]]; then
    # OSX
    if [ -t 0 ]; then
      base64 "$@"
    else
      cat /dev/stdin | base64 "$@"
    fi
  else
    # Linux
    if [ -t 0 ]; then
      base64 -w 0 "$@"
    else
      cat /dev/stdin | base64 -w 0 "$@"
    fi
  fi
}

# Usage
@base64 DSC_0251.JPG
cat DSC_0251.JPG | @base64
```

#### As Shell Script

Create `base64.sh` file with following content:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
if [[ "${OSTYPE}" = darwin* ]]; then
  # OSX
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    base64 "$@"
  else
    cat /dev/stdin | base64 "$@"
  fi
else
  # Linux
  if [ -t 0 ]; then
    base64 -w 0 "$@"
  else
    cat /dev/stdin | base64 -w 0 "$@"
  fi
fi
```

Make it executable:

```bash
chmod a+x base64.sh
```

Usage:

```bash
./base64.sh DSC_0251.JPG
cat DSC_0251.JPG | ./base64.sh
```

## Decode

Get you readable data back:

```bash
base64 -d DSC_0251.base64 > DSC_0251.JPG
```

--

### UPDATE - On MacOS Monterey or the latest

```bash
# Instead of base64 DSC_0251.JPG
base64 -i DSC_0251.JPG
```

If you want to save the output in a file,

```bash
# Instead of base64 -w 0 DSC_0251.JPG > DSC_0251.JPG.base64
base64 -i DSC_0251.JPG -o DSC_0251.JPG.base64
```

Comment: `-w 0` this parameter is very important in many cases. Ex. If we are running directly into the command line.
Thanks!

Comment: BTW on OSX I'm getting `base64: invalid option -- w`. When it's removed, I get `Unable to open '0': No such file or directory`. See [this](https://superuser.com/questions/120796/how-to-encode-base64-via-command-line) instead.

Comment: @coblr In _OSX_, you need to remove `-w 0`.

Comment: pay attention to -w 0

Answer (score 41):

There is a Linux command for that: [base64](http://linux.die.net/man/1/base64)

```
base64 DSC_0251.JPG >DSC_0251.b64
```

To assign result to variable use

```
test=`base64 DSC_0251.JPG`
```

Comment: `base64 -d DSC_0251.b64 > DSC_0251.JPG` can get you readable data back.

Answer (score 4):

If you need input from termial, try this

```
lc=`echo -n "xxx_${yyy}_iOS" |  base64`
```

`-n`  option will not input "\n" character to base64 command.

Comment: `-n` option is the key when using echo.

Answer (score 3):

Base 64 for html:

```
file="DSC_0251.JPG"
type=$(identify -format "%m" "$file" | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
echo "data:image/$type;base64,$(base64 -w 0 "$file")"
```

Answer (score 1):

To base64 it and put it in your clipboard:

```
file="test.docx"
base64 -w 0 $file  | xclip -selection clipboard
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be very cautious when using `echo` (as many answers here), because it will add a newline character at the end, distorting your encoded string (leading to e.g. incorrect passwords) due to these ominous [extra encoded characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58646381/what-does-it-mean-or-what-is-cg): `Cg==` added at the end of the encoded string:

For example, if we have this string to encode:

```
$ MINIO_SECRET_KEY=VsarGnNADHGv
```

With `printf' it will look like this (correct):

```
$ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(printf $MINIO_SECRET_KEY | base64)" && echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
VnNhckduTkFESEd2
```

... but with `echo` like this (incorrect):

```
$ AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="$(echo $MINIO_SECRET_KEY | base64)" && echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
VnNhckduTkFESEd2Cg==
```

Answer (score 0):

On macOS Monterey, you would use:

```
base64 -i image.jpg
```

Comment: Please make more obvious what additional insight you contribute beyond existing and better explained answers. I.e. what is the difference of your solution and why is it a relevant advantage over what was already given?

Comment: I tried all of the other solutions in this post myself and none would work as it now needs a -i switch in order to specify the file name to be used.

Comment: Interesting, please [edit] to improve your answer post with that explanation. Make sure to explain what "now" means. What changed, when, how, why?