# what does it mean, or what is Cg==

Tags: base64, decode, encode, hashcode

Could someone tell me what `Cg==` means, I just know it's related to Base64.

I have searched but I still don't have a correct answer or an idea of ​​what it is, and I don't have much knowledge about base64

Comment: Not sure what you mean, but if you decode `cg==` you get the letter `r`

Comment: As you are new to this site, please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before posting. Show us what you have tried to help us help you.

Answer (score 18):

**Cg==** is the base64 encode of the new line character in the latest position. So if you want to encode `ABC` you will get `QUJD`, however if you include a "return character" after `ABC` you will get `QUJDCg==`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `hexdump` or `xxd` to reveal the actual value of the character in hexadecimal. In the case of `Cg==`, it's a linefeed (`0A`) which can be verified with the following:

```sh
❯ echo -n "Cg==" | base64 -d | hexdump -C
00000000  0a                                                |.|
00000001
```

Answer (score 2):

In my experience `Cg==` arises from passing a string (usually credentials) to `base64` using `echo` (without the `-n` switch and thus appending the default newline character at the end) rather than e.g. with `printf`.