# Authentication required error while using curl command

Tags: linux, unix, curl

I am trying to use curl command , but I keep on getting Authentication required error time and again.The part of reponse is shown below :-

```
"Authentication Required" response (307)
```

I am working on a network which is behind a proxy server. So have tried to provide the proxy authentication during the request too. But have not been successfull.
Please suggest a solution.

Comment: On a 307 GET request, the answer 'Location' head attribute should also contain a redirect URI to follow, isn't this the case?

Comment: @AndreaSalicetti no the answer doesn't have a Location attribute in it.The response which I am getting is                                                           <HEAD><TITLE>Authentication Required</TITLE></HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="white" FGCOLOR="black"><H1>Authentication Required</H1><HR>
<FONT FACE="Helvetica,Arial"><B>
</B></FONT>
<HR>
<!-- default "Authentication Required" response (307) -->
</BODY>

Answer (score 0):

if the URL you are trying to access is behind a login wall, you need to supply the HTTP Header "Authorization". 
for example, if the server accepts basic authorization: 
header=Authorization, value="Basic user:password".
replace user and password with your account credentials.

see related answer: [Setting authorization using CURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044315/how-to-set-the-authorization-header-using-curl)

Good Luck!