# Cassandra Data import from remote CSV using cqlsh COPY

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

If this is possible in Cassandra. Data import from remote CSV using `cqlsh COPY` .

```
copy transc from 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/abc/abc/abc.csv' with header=true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No, you can't import data from remote csv directly**

But if you are using linux you can do this with `curl+cqlsh`

```
curl 'csv_url' | cqlsh node_ip -u username -p username -k keyspace_name -e "copy views from stdin with header = true"
```

Example :

```
curl 'https://pastebin.com/raw/Re6JPaX4' | cqlsh 192.168.65.199 -u cassandra -p cassandra -k test -e "copy views from stdin with header = true"
```

Comment: It worked for csv that we do have access. But for s3 security reason its not working . I am using boto3 for that.

Comment: You can add authorization on curl check that http://stackoverflow.com/a/3044340/2320144