# HTTP's Login Methods

Tags: http, methods

I am trying to Login a device wif its IP in Web Base Mode via Chrome, in the first step I see a user/password window like the following picture...

HTTP Login Page :

[image]

Now i want to know how i can login into dis device through  Http connection in CLI or other programming languages.
I found in Google's searches dis trick ( http://user:password@ip ) to login into the Device, but it doesn't work for me.
could you please help me if there is any solution to solve my problem?

Comment: sorry i don't know why , have been changed my word in post

Answer (score 0):

This is http basic auth, you can login it with probably any languages or cli tools for http requests.

Here is example curl request with auth: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3044340/1603055

Comment: thank you for your attention, is there a public and cross-platform way?