# Authentication error with curl request to download file

Tags: curl, networking, basic-authentication, tls1.2

I would like to download a file from the following link (direct download link) :

https://download.spaces.hightail.com/api/v1/download/sp-79272721-ef49-4de4-a239-01f5be0692a7?downloadFile=true&redirectOnError=%2Freceive%2FSxnIY0QbDr

In browser when I hit the above url, it gives me the following error : "Credentials are required to access this resource."

To overcome this, first I access the base url (given below) in the browser and then from another tab hit the direct link. This allow me to download the file without credential required error.  https://spaces.hightail.com/receive/SxnIY0QbDr  <--- Base url

I would like to download the same file with curl using direct download link. However I get the same 'credential required' error.

1. How can I download the file using curl from direct download link and
   avoid "credential required" error ?
2. Why do I need to access the base url first before accessing the
   download link in the browser ?

May be base url share some authentication information with the browser and the same is used by browser later, but I don't have clear understanding.

Thanks !!!

Comment: Some useful link is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044315/how-to-set-the-authorization-header-using-curl

Answer (score 0):

The way I solved this issue is :

- Get the request headers details (raw data) from browser developer
  tool when downloading the file using browser and store them in a local file. It also contains cookie which is used
  for authentication.
- Get the certificate (.pem) file. Since I am using some proxy server, I got it from the proxy server admin console.
- Execute the following curl command :

  > curl -v -S -x proxy_ip:proxy_port -H "$(cat raw_header)" --cacert
  > cert.pem -o ./myfile
  > https://download.spaces.hightail.com/api/v1/download/sp-79272721-ef49-4de4-a239-01f5be0692a7